# Using a vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker in a Vue Single File Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app. My app is mainly composed of single file components. I'm trying to use the `vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker` [component](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker) in one of my components.

At this time, my app runs. When I click on the date field, the current date appears. However, I never see the popup calendar. I also don't see any errors in the Chrome Console window. I don't understand why this isn't working. Currently, I have the following:

**page.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <date-picker v-model="myDate" :config="myDateConfig"></date-picker>
        <br />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import datePicker from 'vue-bootstrap-datetimepicker';

    export default {
        components: {
            datePicker
        },

        data: function() {
            return {
                myDate: null,
                myDateConfig: {
                    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                    useCurrent: true,
                    showClear: true,
                    showClose: true
                },
        }
    }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
window.Vue = Vue;

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import moment from 'moment';
import 'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css';

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component:require('./page.vue').default }
];

const router = new VueRouter({ 
  routes:routes
});

const app = new Vue({ 
    router,
    el: '#app'
    data: {}
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DatePicker</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>    

  <body>
    <div id="app">      
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the popup calendar show up when I click in the `date-picker`?

Comment: Is it ok with other browsers, for instance: Firefox?

Comment: No. It does not work in Firefox.

Comment: any logs in console?